# Fitting a distribution to the histograms obtained for a group

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

For a group of subjects (n=10), I have a normalized histogram for each subject.  Now I am defining a distribution from all these histogram. What would be a reasonable approach to it? E.g., is there a method that I can use to combine all histogram to fit the distribution? Or to fit the distribution to the average of the normalized frequencies across the group?

I will be using R to carry out the analysis.

Comment: I hope you have some prior knowledge what kinds of distributions may be applicable. With only ten subjects it is almost impossible to tell what the population distribution is. Maybe even difficult to distinguish among normal, uniform, and exponential. I don't know enough about your situation to say how/whether to combine data for different subjects. Might be useful to look at general topic 'density estimation' or 'KDE' for kernel density estimation. In particular, R procedure `density(x)` gives a density estimator for data vector x (sequences of x & y coordinates that can be plotted).

Comment: @BruceET Thank you.  The distribution appears to be "normal".  I have checked the "fitdistr" function, which takes the whole data set.  In my case, I have the histogram already (normalised frequency and corresponding measurements (0:0.4:2)).  What would you recommend as next steps?